# Hide a Submit if Theres no data PHP

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this form working with PHPMailer. The thing is, I need to hide the button Submit if there's no data in the query I use for the emails of the customers.

```
<form method="POST" action="enviarprueba.php" style="font-family: Calibri" >
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $nombre_cliente;?>" name="nombre" size="35" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $email_cliente;?>" name="emailenvio" size="35" hidden >
    <input type="text" value='http://sys.cromatix.cl/documentos/mensaje_cliente1.php?cod_documento=<?php echo $cod_documento;?>' name="cotizacion" size="35" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="Envio Avances Cromatix" name="asunto" size="35" hidden> <br>
    <input type="text" value="<br>Estimado Cliente: <br> Nos dirijimos a usted para informarle que la mercaderia ha sido despachada como se evidencia en las imagenes anexas." name="msg" size="35" hidden>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Aviso de Entrega" name="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: What did you try for that? I can't see a PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the variable `$email_cliente` is null if your query result is empty.
Then you can just display the submit button if the email is not empty.

```
<form method="POST" action="enviarprueba.php" style="font-family: Calibri" >
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $nombre_cliente;?>" name="nombre" size="35" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $email_cliente;?>" name="emailenvio" size="35" hidden >
    <input type="text" value='http://sys.cromatix.cl/documentos/mensaje_cliente1.php?cod_documento=<?php echo $cod_documento;?>' name="cotizacion" size="35" hidden>
    <input type="text" value="Envio Avances Cromatix" name="asunto" size="35" hidden> <br>
    <input type="text" value="<br>Estimado Cliente: <br> Nos dirijimos a usted para informarle que la mercaderia ha sido despachada como se evidencia en las imagenes anexas." name="msg" size="35" hidden>
 <?php if ($email_cliente !== null): ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar Aviso de Entrega" name="submit">
<?php endif ?>
</form>
```

Comment: Where I work at, they wanted it to be empty cells so instead of Null, I used ' '  . Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replacing `hidden` with `required`. this will make it so unless all required fields have a value set you wont be able to submit the form.

See here for details on this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

Comment: The thing is I wanted it to not be seen. Thx either way

Comment: @CristobalHernandez I see, that also means you can't validate the email. do you pull the data using an SQL query? if so you could change the query to have `WHERE (col_email IS NOT NULL or col_email != '') and..` or `WHERE  col_email like '%@%'` which would alleviate the issue.

Another option is to check the `$_POST['emailenvio']` and have that throw an error if the length is 0 using `strlen()` or (Either a Message box or return to the page and show the error)